# My android app "stops unexpectedly"

Tags: java, android, xml

I have recently got into writing android apps and have hit a brick wall very early on that I can't figure out, and i'm sure it's mind numbingly simple.

Everytime I run it in my emulator, I get the "Stopped unexpectedly" error :/

[Files](http://pastebin.com/qrwUDVV0)

The main ".java" file and the main.xml are in there, just scroll down.

EDIT: Fixed now, just needed a simple clean :3

Comment: It's in the pastebin, along with my main. I didn't want a massive question

Comment: yeh sorry saw it too late. :)

Comment: Mhm actually no, phillip sounds right, but I can't find that view either. Maybe you had it in the past and android choked on the generation. Try cleaning your project via `Project -> Clean`. After that android regenerates everything from scratch.

Comment: :L worked like a charm. This is my first day using eclipse and i've been away from Java for years. Thanks muchly :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your layout XML, there's an invalid element named `EditText2`. There's no such view in the Android SDK, remove the "2".

Comment: I can't find it anywhere :/. I've looked through it and used search

Comment: Are you sure you're running the right code? Maybe uninstall the app from the emulator (via the usual menus) and try again :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't scroll down beyond the stacktrace in pastebin.